# Hours and minutes from date in android

Tags: java, android, android-date

I have java util date as `Thu Feb 28 15:35:00 GMT+00:00 2013`

How to convert it to `HH:MM`.

I am trying to do this via below snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        return formatter.format(objDate);
```

Its giving right result for `dd mmm` but always giving minutes as 02 for `HH:MM`

Please suggest me what is wrong in this function?

Comment: "M" is month, minutes is "m"

Comment: You want date in 24 hour and minute format am i right ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`MM` is the *month* value in `SimpleDateFormat`. You want `mm`. Note that using `HH` will give you the 24 hour clock (00-23)... you can use `hh` for the 12 hour clock (01-12) but you probably also want the am/pm designator in that case.

See the [documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details of the various format specifiers available.

Also note that for internationalization purposes, you might be better off with:

```
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
```

... so that it will use the appropriate "short time format" for the given locale. That's appropriate if this is for display (human-readable) purposes; for computer-readable formats, it's fine to create a custom format but I'd recommend explicitly using `Locale.US` to avoid getting different calendars and format symbols (e.g. the time separator).

Comment: Thanks +1 and accepted the answer. You have saved my time and given valuable knowledge

Comment: It's getTimeInstance(), not getTimeInstant().

Answer (score 4):

use

```
String str ="Thu Feb 28 15:35:00 GMT+00:00 2013";

SimpleDateFormat formatter_from = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss ZZ yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat formatter_to = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

try {
    java.util.Date d = formatter_from.parse(str);

    System.out.println(formatter_to.format(d));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's then the 12-hour clock with no am/pm designator, which may well *not* be desired.