# How to reformat time format?

Tags: java, android, datetime, time, time-format

I am working on android project and i receive from API the time in format like this "10:12:57 am" (12 hour format) and I want to display it in format "10:12" just like this (on a 24 hour clock). How to reformat that time?

So `12:42:41 am` should become `00:42`. And `02:13:39 pm` should be presented as `14:13`.

Comment: Is the returned object from the API a String? If "10:12:57 am" is a String then you simply use `substring(0,5)` to get the first five characters from the String.

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132878/hours-and-minutes-from-date-in-android)

Comment: @HuzaifaIftikhar but it is 12 hours system, and i want it in 24 hours

Comment: How will the API return the time when the hours is less than 10? Is it like "09:12:57 am" or "9:12:57 am"? Depending on this you can easily convert it to 24-hour format on your own.

Comment: Not a duplicate of [that linked Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15132878/642706). That Question involves a moment, a date with time-of-day and with an offset-from-UTC. This Question is about a time-of-day alone, no date, no offset, no time zone.

Comment: Ideally the API should be able to give you a string in ISO 8601 format, that is, like `10:12:57` (24 hours). And yiou should display the time according to the user’s locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **java.time** (Modern Approach)

```
String str = "10:12:57 pm";

DateTimeFormatter formatter_from = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US ); //Use pattern symbol "hh" for 12 hour clock
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(str.toUpperCase(), formatter_from );
DateTimeFormatter formatter_to = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm" , Locale.US ); // "HH" stands for 24 hour clock

System.out.println(localTime.format(formatter_to));
```

See BasilBourque answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52471520/10372900) and OleV.V. answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50450369/10372900) for better explanation.

Using **SimpleDateFormat**

```
String str = "10:12:57 pm";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter_from = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US); 

    //Locale is optional. You might want to add it to avoid any cultural differences.

    SimpleDateFormat formatter_to = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);

    try {
        Date d = formatter_from.parse(str);

        System.out.println(formatter_to.format(d));

    } catch (ParseException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If your input is 10:12:57 am, output will be 10:12. And if string is 10:12:57 pm, output will be 22:12.

Comment: error ==> Unparseable date : "10:12:57 am" at offset 9

Comment: Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030767/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-2014-06-04-at-offset-5)

Comment: Not at all but edit your answer to be like mine to every provide from it .thanks

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: This code misuses a date-with-time-of-day class to hold a time-of-day-only value. Square peg in a round hole.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime                                                    // Represent a time-of-day, without a date and without a time zone.
.parse(                                                      // Parse an input string to be a `LocalTime` object.
    "10:12:57 am".toUpperCase() ,                            // The cultural norm in the United States expects the am/pm to be in all-uppercase. So we convert our input value to uppercase.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm:ss a" , Locale.US )  // Specify a formatting pattern to match the input. 
)                                                            // Returns a `LocalTime` object.
.format(                                                     // Generate text representing the value in this date-time object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm" , Locale.US )       // Note that `HH` in uppercase means 24-hour clock, not 12-hour.
)                                                            // Returns a `String`.
```

> 10:12

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible `Date` & `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat` classes.

The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day in a generic 24-hour day, without a date and without a time zone.

Parse your string input as a `LocalTime` object.

```
String input = ( "10:12:57 am" );
DateTimeFormatter fInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm:ss a" , Locale.US );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input.toUpperCase() , fInput );  // At least in the US locale, the am/pm is expected to be in all uppercase: AM/PM. So we call `toUppercase` to convert input accordingly.
```

> lt.toString(): 10:12:57

Generate a `String` with text in the hour-minute format you desire. Note that `HH` in uppercase means 24-hour clock.

```
DateTimeFormatter fOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm" , Locale.US );
String output = lt.format( fOutput );
```

> output: 10:12

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use such formatters:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatterFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
SimpleDateFormat formatterTo = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

Date date = formatterFrom.parse("10:12:57 pm");
System.out.println(formatterTo.format(date));
```

Comment: i test it and it throw parse exception !!

Comment: error ==> Unparseable date : "10:12:57 pm" at offset 9

Comment: Okay, try this one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
   SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
   try {
         Date date = parseFormat.parse("10:12:57 pm");
         System.out.println(parseFormat.format(date) + " = " + displayFormat.format(date));
       } 
   catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

The gives:

```
10:12:57 pm = 22:12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str ="10:12:57 pm";

SimpleDateFormat formatter_from = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat formatter_to = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",Locale.US);

try {
    Date d = formatter_from.parse(str);

    System.out.println(formatter_to.format(d));

} catch (ParseException e) {           
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome SimpleDateFormat class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.